# Ad-Hoc type conversion in JOOQ DSL query

Tags: jooq, custom-type

scenario:
we store some encrypted data in db as blob. When reading/saving it, we need to decrypt/encrypt it using an external service.
because it is actually a spring bean using an external service, we cannot use the code generator like dealing with enums.

I don't want to use `dslContext.select(field1, field2.convertFrom).from(TABLE_NAME)` because you need to specify every fields of the table.

It is convenient to use `dslContext.selectFrom(TABLE_NAME)`. wonder if any way we can register the converter bean in such query to perform encrypt and decrypt on the fly.

Thanks

Edit: I ended up using a service to encrypt/decrypt the value when it is actually used. Calling an external service is relatively expensive. Sometimes the value isn't used in the request. It may not make sense to always decrypt the value when reading from db using the converter.

Answer (score 2):

> because it is actually a spring bean using an external service, we cannot use the code generator like dealing with enums.

Why not? Just because Spring favours dependency injection, and you currently (as of jOOQ 3.15) [cannot inject anything into jOOQ `Converter` and `Binding` instances](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5266), doesn't mean you can't use other means of looking up such a service. Depending on what you have available, you could use some JNDI lookup, or other means to discover that service when needed, from within your `Converter`.

Another option would be to use a [`ConverterProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/converter-provider/) and register your logic inside of that. That wouldn't produce your custom type inside of jOOQ records, but whenver you convert your blob to your custom data type, e.g. using reflection.

**How to access Spring Beans without Dependency Injection?**

If you need to access your Spring Beans you don't need Dependency Injection. Simply create the following class and you can get beans from the static method `getBean()`:

```java
@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> type) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        ApplicationContextHolder.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: With Spring you can implement ApplicationContextAware and set the ApplicationContext to a static field. and then provide a static method to get the beans

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: That sounds like what I had in mind. Perhaps you could show an example in an answer?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Hehe, I meant in your own answer, to get your own credit :)

Comment: Oh it's not worth an own answer. And I've probably posted this code snippet on SO a dozen times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew ApplicationContextAware, but didn't think of using static method in this case. I will give it a try, one improvement might be to cache the bean refence instead of calling getBean everytime.

Comment: @LukasEder Hi, wonder if it is possible to support sth like:  dslContext.selectFrom(TABLE_NAME)
        .where(TABLE_NAME.ID.eq(myObjectId)).converters(Lists.of(converter(TABLE_NAME.FIELD_NAME, myConverter))
        .fetchOneInto(MY_TABLE_RECORD.class).  sorry about the fomatting in a comment. Hope I have made my idea clear.

Comment: @ryang: you know what has better formatting and will even produce better formatted answers? A new question! :)

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks, maybe I can submit a feature request and we can discuss it in github.

Comment: Thanks for the hint of using static method to get reference to ApplicationContext. I tried the solution but spotbugs reported a warning that "it is not a good practice to use a instance to set static field". What I ended up doing is to use  a spring service to encrypt/decrypt the value when it is used, which may be a better solution comparing using conververs given it is calling an external service (expensive).